# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{b5fddb4} not attached to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

> User-space exception detected!
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{b5fddb4}
> (cb02f463-644e-4d0f-b742-696dba6c214d) not attached to an activity.
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:928)
> at
> com.flixo.videostreaming.fragment.HomeFragment.displayData(HomeFragment.java:221)
> at
> com.flixo.videostreaming.fragment.HomeFragment.access$700(HomeFragment.java:47)
> at
> com.flixo.videostreaming.fragment.HomeFragment$1.onSuccess(HomeFragment.java:198)
> at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:354)
> at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:513)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
> 2023-08-07 16:54:32.057  8577-8577  AndroidRuntime
> com.flixo.videostreaming             D  Shutting down VM 2023-08-07
> 16:54:32.071  8577-8577  AndroidRuntime
> com.flixo.videostreaming             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.flixo.videostreaming, PID: 8577
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment
> HomeFragment{b5fddb4} (cb02f463-644e-4d0f-b742-696dba6c214d) not
> attached to an activity.
> at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.onUserException(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:307)
> at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:398)
> at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:513)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment
> HomeFragment{b5fddb4} (cb02f463-644e-4d0f-b742-696dba6c214d) not
> attached to an activity.
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:928)
> at
> com.flixo.videostreaming.fragment.HomeFragment.displayData(HomeFragment.java:221)
> at
> com.flixo.videostreaming.fragment.HomeFragment.access$700(HomeFragment.java:47)
> at
> com.flixo.videostreaming.fragment.HomeFragment$1.onSuccess(HomeFragment.java:198)
> at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:354)

//all files uploaded github
https://github.com/akash-softintra/player.git

please give me a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs when Fragment calls context when it is not attached to Activity.

If you look at Fragment's Life Cycle, you can find onAttach.
The getContext provided by Fragment sometimes returns null
To use context securely, go from onAttach to the factor
We recommend using context.

Try the code below.

[image]

Comment: not working sir